# How do I update state of a functional component from a class component in order to display items from a map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, gatsby

I have a StoreDetails functional componenet in Gatsby JS, it is rendering products conditionally from a map in graphQL that match the state value using UseState hook. I have a class component drop down menu that currently manually is populated with sku'ids that would match the condition to display in the state and map conditional statement. I want the dropdown to change the state of the functional component so the right product shows when it is selected in the drop down. I was playing around with passing the state function as a prop, but I got rerender issues, quite stuck here.

The key is at this line `{value.skuId === sku.skuId ?` How do I change that based on the option dropdown when it's still inside the map

thanks ahead of time

Here is my code so far

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
// import Alert from '../components/Alert';
import { navigate } from "gatsby";
import Img from "gatsby-image"





const StoreHero = styled.section`
    width:1280px;
    margin:0 auto;
`

class Alert extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        //console.log(props);

        this.state = {test:"test",hello:"hello1",hash:props.hash}
    }
    render(){
        const { test, hello, hash } = this.state

        //console.log(hash);

        return(
            <div>{hash}</div>
        )
    }
}


class ShowItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'coconut'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    console.log(event.target.value);

    // Right here is where I want to change the state of the value variable below so
    // that the correct product is shown based on the dropdown sku selection

  }


  render() {


    return (

          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="sku_HAD1kUsbV3GpgW">sku_HAD1kUsbV3GpgW</option>
            <option value="sku_HACMgLjJBZFR7A">sku_HACMgLjJBZFR7A</option>
          </select>


    );
  }
}

class Product extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          stripe: null
        };

                this.loadStripeLib = this.loadStripeLib.bind(this);
                this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.loadStripeLib()
      }

      async loadStripeLib() {
        try {
          const stripe = await loadStripe('pk_test_random');
          this.setState({ stripe });
        } catch {
          // do nothing
        }
      }

      handleSubmit(sku, productId){
          return event => {
              event.preventDefault();
              this.state.stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                items: [{sku, quantity: 1}],
                successUrl: `http://localhost:8000/store/${productId}#success`,
                cancelUrl: `http://localhost:8000/store/${productId}#cancelled`,
              }).then(function (result) {
                // Display result.error.message to your customer
                console.error(result);
              });
          }
            }


      render(){
                    const { id, currency, price, name, productId } = this.props

                    const priceFloat = (price / 100).toFixed(2)
                    const formattedPrice = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                    style: 'currency',
                    currency,
                    }).format(priceFloat)

          return(
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit(id, productId)}>
                                <h2>
                                    {name} ({formattedPrice})
                                </h2>
                <button type="submit">Buy Now</button>

              </form>
          )
      }

}

const StoreDetails = ({data, location}) =>{

  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    skuId: "sku_HAD1kUsbV3GpgW"
  });



    //console.log(value);



    return(
        <Layout>
            <StoreHero>
                        <Alert test="test" hello="hello" hash={location.hash}/>

            {/* <ShowItem props={data}/> */}                                    

              {data.allDatoCmsStore.edges.map(({ node: sku }) => (
                <>
                {value.skuId === sku.skuId ?
                  <>
                    <ShowItem setValue={setValue}/>
                    <Product
                      key={sku.id}
                      id={sku.skuId}
                      productId={sku.productId}
                      currency="cad"
                      price={sku.price}
                      name={sku.title}
                    />
                    <Img fixed={sku.image.fixed}/>
                  </>
                :
                  null
                }

                </>
              ))}

            </StoreHero>
        </Layout>
    )

}

export default StoreDetails

export const query = graphql`
  query StoreDeatailsQuery($slug: String!)  {
    allDatoCmsStore(filter: {productId: {eq: $slug}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          price
          productId
          skuId
          title
          id
          image{
            fixed{
              ...GatsbyDatoCmsFixed
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    allStripeSku {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            currency
            price
            attributes {
              name
            }
            image
            localFiles {
              childImageSharp {
                fixed(width: 125) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was overcomplicating it, I have more to do, but changing it to this fixed it for me

```
const StoreDetails = ({data, location}) =>{

  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    skuId: "sku_HAD1kUsbV3GpgW"
  });


  const run = (event) =>{
    console.log(event);
    setValue({skuId:event})
  }


    return(
        <Layout>
            <StoreHero>
                        <Alert test="test" hello="hello" hash={location.hash}/>

            {/* <ShowItem props={data}/> */}                                    

              {data.allDatoCmsStore.edges.map(({ node: sku }) => (
                <>
                {value.skuId === sku.skuId ?
                  <>
                  <select onChange={(event) => run(event.target.value)}>
                    <option value="sku_HAD1kUsbV3GpgW">sku_HAD1kUsbV3GpgW</option>
                    <option value="sku_HACMgLjJBZFR7A">sku_HACMgLjJBZFR7A</option>
                  </select>
                    {/* <ShowItem setValue={setValue}/> */}
                    <Product
                      key={sku.id}
                      id={sku.skuId}
                      productId={sku.productId}
                      currency="cad"
                      price={sku.price}
                      name={sku.title}
                    />
                    <Img fixed={sku.image.fixed}/>
                  </>
                :
                  null
                }

                </>
              ))}

            </StoreHero>
        </Layout>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

React UI will change by reacting to state changes. if two child component need the same data (in this case the selected value). then the state of selected value should be on the parent component (in `StoreDetails`) so the `Product` will change when the value state on `StoreDetails` is changed by the function sent to the `onChange` as props.

Comment: could you give me a example in code, based off of my code. I put a solution that is working, but I would prefer to use react's intented use of state.

Comment: IMO you already doing it right the react way. keep making view component as dumb as possible, send function as props to the dumb component, put state on the parent if you want the the component to re-render. here's a similar code for filtering list but use checkbox https://codepen.io/jessnology/pen/QWwwKxM